How can I search for matching rows of pairs of values in PySpark?
I have an extremely large table with columns id1, id2, value.
id1 and id2 are not unique on their own, but the pair of them is unique.
I have a pyspark dataframe with unique pairs that I want to get the value for:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("session") \
    .getOrCreate()


data = [
    ("a1", "Z1"),
    ("b1", "Y1"),
    ("a1", "Y1"),
    ("c1", "X1")
]

pyspark_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id1", "id2"])

My naive way of doing this is this:
id1_list = [row.id1 for row in pyspark_df.select("id1").collect()]
id2_list = [row.id2 for row in pyspark_df.select("id2").collect()]

def get_values(id1_list, id2_list):

    table = spark.table("table")
    table = table.filter(F.col("id1").isin(id1_list))
    table = table.filter(F.col("id2").isin(id2_list))

    return table

get_values(id1_list, id2_list)

However, this gets all rows with a matching id1 and all rows with a matching id2, not the unique pairs. I want to just get the pairs, and I want to do so in a way that is efficient in an extremely large database.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something, are you saying that you want to get a list of value that match your id1 and id2 pair?

can you give an example of the unique pairs?

If the query [id1, id2] dataframe is small then you can use broadcast join. Broadcast the smaller dataframe.
https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-broadcast-join-with-example/
